# Topological proof of sum of two continuous functions

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $X$ be a topological space and $f,g:X \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. I want to show that $$(f+g)^{-1}((a,b))$$ is open in $X$. And I found this $$(f+g)^{-1}((a,b))=\bigcup_{a<t_{1}+t_{2}<b}\big(f^{-1}((a-t_{1},t_{2}))\cap g^{-1}((t_{1},b-t_{2}))\big) $$

Is it correct? If it is, it seems the equality is complicated. Is there another way to show that the equality holds?

Comment: At some point, this comes down to the fact that addition in $\mathbb{R}$ is continuous as a function $+: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, which is no easier or harder than a proof like the one above.

Comment: @Randall I think that the proof of the equality above is easier.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @Randall's comment, let us first verify the case $X = \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$, with $f$ and $g$ the two projections. Then $f + g$ is exactly the map $(+) : \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. It suffices to show that each
$$(+)^{-1}(a, b) = \{ (x, y) \mid a < x + y < b\}$$
is open. If $z_0 = x_0 + y_0 \in (a, b)$, then $(z_0 - 2\varepsilon, z_0 + 2\varepsilon) \subset (a, b)$ for some $\varepsilon > 0$. Then $(x_0, y_0) \in (x_0 - \varepsilon, x_0 + \varepsilon) \times (y_0 - \varepsilon, y_0 + \varepsilon) \subset (+)^{-1}(a, b)$. Since $(x_0, y_0) \in (+)^{-1}(a, b)$ was arbitrary, this set must be open.

The general case actually reduces to this special case since $f + g$ is the composition
$$X \xrightarrow{(f,g)} \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \xrightarrow{+} \mathbb{R}$$
and therefore is continuous.

If you choose an $\varepsilon$ for each $(x_0, y_0)$ (for instance by setting $\varepsilon = \min(z_0 - a, b- z_0)/2$) then you can turn the check above into an equality similar to the one in the question:
$$(+)^{-1}(a, b) = \bigcup_{x_0 + y_0 \in (a, b)} (x_0 - \varepsilon, x_0 + \varepsilon) \times (y_0 - \varepsilon, y_0 + \varepsilon),$$
where $\varepsilon = \varepsilon(x_0, y_0)$ depends on $(x_0, y_0)$.

Comment: Note that this answer uses the notation $(p, q)$ for both ordered pairs and intervals. If any of the individual instances is not clear from context then feel free to [edit].

Answer (score 0):

The following characterizations of continuity are easy to derive and will serve you well in problems like this:

1. (Strong form) $f$ is continuous at $x$ iff for every neighborhood $N$ of $f(x)$, $f^{-1}(N)$ is a neighborhood of $x$.
2. (Weak form) $f$ is continuous at $x$ iff for some neighborhood basis $\mathcal B_{f(x)}$ of $f(x)$, for every $B\in \mathcal B_{f(x)}$ we have $f^{-1}(B)$ is a neighborhood of $x$.

Continuity is of course equivalent to continuity at all points.

Here a “neighborhood” $N$ of $x$ is a set (not necessarily open itself) with $N\supseteq U\ni x$ for some open $U$.

Use the strong form when you know you are continuous and want to prove other things, and the weak form when you want to prove continuity itself.

With this characterization continuity becomes a little more intuitive - if $f$ and $g$ vary by at most $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ then their sum varies by at most $\epsilon$, and that can be the basis for your proof.

More formally, for each $x\in X$, and each $\epsilon>0$, we have

$$(f+g)^{-1}(B_\epsilon(f(x)+g(x))) \supseteq f^{-1}(B_{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}(f(x)))\cap g^{-1}(B_{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}(g(x))),$$
where the right hand side is a neighborhood of $x$ by continuity of $f$ and $g$, and so the left hand side is a neighborhood as well. Since the balls form a neighborhood basis for each point in $\mathbb R$, continuity follows from the weak form of the definition.